# How to find out to which COM port the device is plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, com-port

I have a bluetooth device. I need to know which COM port it currently occupies. When I open Device manager it lists three different COM ports. How to find out which one is the one that has the bluetooth device plugged in?

Comment: What makes you think that a BT device would connect to a COM port?  COM ports normally have nothing to do with Bluetooth but RS232 serial devices (or emulated USB serial devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to disable one by one and see which is the right one, or with a [C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938442/how-to-find-which-serial-port-is-currently-used).